# Windows Github basics and conflict handling (like VSS)

Tags: windows, github, conflict, rollback, merge-conflict-resolution

I'm new to Git / GitHub (used VSS in past). Based on my [SO Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10722989) I'm using **[Windows GitHub](http://windows.github.com/)** Its user friendly compared to the command prompt based Git bash stuff. In particular the sync feature, no worries about SSH, etc...

I'm trying to understand the flow in terms of VSS (atleast basic check in /out & rollback). My understanding -

> 1. Initially, **clone** a remote repository locally (probably like checkout the whole proj in VSS but in Git its a separate clone copy)
> 2. Later I just need to **Pull** (like get latest in VSS). Make changes, **commit** (all done on local cloned branch) - like staging checkins
> 3. Finally, **Push** the commit(staged changes) on the remote repository (like final checkin as in VSS).

**Can the tool detect / handle conflicts?**
I found an ***excellent [SO Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13210706/github-conflict-resolving)*** but need to confirm. I believe I'll get a conflict message while Push. Then I'll have to manually alter the file (merge changes) and then Push it again (like we do merge in VSS). Do I've to use commandline or is it possible from within the tool?

And how can I **rollback to a prev version** - from Git bash or tool?

---

I also found some VS.Net source control **[providers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/507343/using-git-with-visual-studio)** and **[extensions](http://code.google.com/p/gitextensions/)** but some got me back to the old SSH and other complex things. I want to keep it simple and make it least complex to encourage my team .. if you know what I mean. VSS was no pain to use or learn :-)

Ref

- [Good Win Github article](http://arstechnica.com/information-technology/2012/05/hands-on-github-for-windows-takes-the-pain-out-of-using-git/)
- [Cool guide for git concepts](http://rogerdudler.github.com/git-guide/)
- [Git Tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/315911/git-for-beginners-the-definitive-practical-guide)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Can the tool detect / handle conflicts?

Yes, but the command line is still recommended: more details in "[On conflict, GitHub for Windows puts me in “rebasing” state, how to go from there?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15149953/on-conflict-github-for-windows-puts-me-in-rebasing-state-how-to-go-from-ther)"

> can I rollback to a prev version - from Git bash or tool?

GitHub for Windows offers different options (rollback, revert, discard), and you even can [undo those operations now](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15545060/6309).